# How to hack latest Spring Framework for OSGi?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, apache-camel, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi

Right now we are developing **IHE HL7 Integration Project**. Where lots of micro-services and dependencies. It's developed by using **Apache Camel 2.18.4**, **Spring Framework 4.3.10.RELEASE** on top of **Spring Boot 1.5.6.RELEASE**.

It's a combination of **Spring Boot Standalone** web application, grew larger and unmanageable. Our thought is to make it modularize by the support of **OSGi bundle** using **Blueprint** on top of **Spring Framework 4.3.10.RELEASE** and **Spring Boot 1.5.6.RELEASE**.

It's would be the best if we are able to hack **OSGi bundle** with reusable **Spring Context**, **Persistance(JPA, MyBatis)** and **Transaction**.

It's impossible to dive fully into **Blueprint** instead of **Spring Framework**. Only want to use the **flavor** of **Blueprint** to make our **Spring Application** **modularize**, **loosely couple** and **JMX compliance**. For example modularize by its:

1. Bundles for Service
2. Bundles for Persistence
3. Bundles for Spring Component
4. Bundles for Camel Component/Endpoint
5. Bundles for Utilities/Miscellaneous

In this perspective we expect the right opinion from the expertise what's the feasibility of our thought. Guideline and reference highly expected.

Comment: Question is VERY broad. Just sharing my 2 cents. Break up your huge application in microservices as well, keep using the same technological stack. Maybe use containers like docker if it makes sense.  Spring + Blueprint together = lots of headaches and problems.

Comment: Yeah agreed here I would look at one technology and MSA.